# Wanting to get hard coded data from php files

Tags: php, parsing, csv, html-agility-pack, filemaker

Forgive me for asking such a general question but I am kind of flooded with options and could really use some opinions on how you would proceede, maybe this can be a bit of a discussion with some points/counter points.

So I am currently working on a new website for a friend's art gallery.

The new website is a mysql backed cms (processwire), the old website is old school hard coded php.

The current items or artworks are hard coded into a function:

```
artinfo($field1,$field2,$field3,$field4,$field5,$field6,)
```

This is just a function that takes several string values and does some formatting to display them on a page.

```
artinfo('abeles-conundrum.jpg','Sigmund Abeles','Conundrum','Lithograph','34 x 24     inches','$1600','');
```

So where I am getting stuck is here. I will have access to their filemaker database that has many fields but no images, and their current admin has all of the images with the names that are on the website.

What I am thinking that I will try to do is use the data on their current website to relate the info in the db to the images.

The reason why I am also not reusing the old images is that they are currently fairly small (max 400px), and would like to use higher res images (around 1200px).

I do have a utility that I built in c# using the html agility pack to pull the relavant fields, but I do also have access to the raw php files as well.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do? Extract the parameters for each call to `artinfo()`? Also, you tagged this with [tag:csv] -- why?

Comment: I apologise that i didn't explain this further. My end goal is to combine all of the data that is in their database with the images that are located on the admin's machine. In order to import all of this I will need a csv file that I can point processwire to. I can then map the fields and bulk upload all of the artworks to the website. So I am going to need to parse the function call everywhere that it appears on the website. Thanks for responding.